# Does anyone know this Chinese poem?

Tags: poetry

My friend gave an English translation of this Chinese poem to me long time ago. It was a long poem and it was about two men, talking by the river and enjoying the moon. It contained a phrase, "Have you seen the moon and the water?" They talk about some things always changing and yet always there, like the moon and the river. I don't remember who wrote it, but I just remember it was beautiful. Does anybody know what this poem is??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the entire translation of this poem?

Answer (score 5):

The poem you are quoting is 前赤壁赋 by 苏轼，and indeed, it is one of the best 赋 in Chinese history.

The part you have in the post is

> **客亦知夫水与月乎**？逝者如斯，而未尝往也，盈虚者如彼，而卒莫消长也。**盖将自其变者而观之，则天地曾不能以一瞬，自其不变者而观之，则物与我皆无尽也**，而又何羡乎？且夫天地之间，物各有主，苟非吾之所有，虽一毫而莫取。惟江上之清风，与山间之明月，耳得之而为声，目遇之而成色，取之无禁，用之不竭，是造物者无尽臧也，而吾与子之所共适。